# Node WebKit, AngularJS & Foundation crash with 0xC0000005 error code

Tags: angularjs, node.js, node-webkit

I have made an application with these components:

- Node.js

  - express (v 4.13.4)
  - Node WebKit (v 0.15.4)
  - ws (v 1.1.0)
- Angular JS (v 1.5.6)
- Foundation

During his life sometimes it crashes for no reason. Usually when I click on a button with an ng-click hook. As you can read on top, the error code is 0xC0000005 but I can not understand what's the problem because at this point the application doesn't write anywhere.

I hope these informations could be enought because the code is really poor.

I've opend the minidump file of chromium and this is the report:

```
Riepilogo dump
--------------
File dump:  0d6bb324-dc25-4ba4-b6dd-3a4e6d761338.dmp : C:\Users\developer\AppData\Local\Crashpad\reports\0d6bb324-dc25-4ba4-b6dd-3a4e6d761338.dmp
Ora ultima scrittura:   06/07/2016 10:24:34
Nome processo:  nw.exe : C:\Users\developer\Documents\DavideB\icconnector\frontend\node_modules\nw\nwjs\nw.exe
Architettura processo:  x64
Codice eccezione:   0xC0000005
Informazioni eccezione: Tentativo di lettura o di scrittura di un indirizzo virtuale da parte di un thread privo delle autorizzazioni di accesso appropriate.
Informazioni heap:  Non presenti

Informazioni di sistema
-----------------------
Versione sistema operativo: 6.3.9600
Versioni CLR:   

Moduli
------
Nome modulo Percorso modulo Versione modulo
----------- --------------- ---------------
nw.exe  C:\Users\developer\Documents\DavideB\icconnector\frontend\node_modules\nw\nwjs\nw.exe   0.0.0.0
ntdll.dll   C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll   6.3.9600.18233
KERNELBASE.dll  C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll  6.3.9600.18264
KERNEL32.DLL    C:\Windows\system32\KERNEL32.DLL    6.3.9600.17415
apphelp.dll C:\Windows\system32\apphelp.dll 6.3.9600.17824
msvcrt.dll  C:\Windows\system32\msvcrt.dll  7.0.9600.17415
SspiCli.dll C:\Windows\system32\SspiCli.dll 6.3.9600.17415
RPCRT4.dll  C:\Windows\system32\RPCRT4.dll  6.3.9600.18292
sechost.dll C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\sechost.dll 6.3.9600.17734
ADVAPI32.dll    C:\Windows\system32\ADVAPI32.dll    6.3.9600.18155
bcryptPrimitives.dll    C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\bcryptPrimitives.dll    6.3.9600.18340
CRYPTBASE.DLL   C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\CRYPTBASE.DLL   6.3.9600.17415
nw_elf.dll  C:\Users\developer\Documents\DavideB\icconnector\frontend\node_modules\nw\nwjs\nw_elf.dll   0.0.0.0
VERSION.dll C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\VERSION.dll 6.3.9600.17415
cfgmgr32.dll    C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\cfgmgr32.dll    6.3.9600.17415
DEVOBJ.dll  C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\DEVOBJ.dll  6.3.9600.17415
WINMMBASE.dll   C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\WINMMBASE.dll   6.3.9600.17415
GDI32.dll   C:\Windows\system32\GDI32.dll   6.3.9600.18344
USER32.dll  C:\Windows\system32\USER32.dll  6.3.9600.18123
MSCTF.dll   C:\Windows\system32\MSCTF.dll   6.3.9600.18081
IMM32.DLL   C:\Windows\system32\IMM32.DLL   6.3.9600.17415
WINMM.dll   C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\WINMM.dll   6.3.9600.17415
combase.dll C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\combase.dll 6.3.9600.18202
WINHTTP.dll C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\WINHTTP.dll 6.3.9600.18340
SHLWAPI.dll C:\Windows\system32\SHLWAPI.dll 6.3.9600.17415
SHELL32.dll C:\Windows\system32\SHELL32.dll 6.3.9600.18231
shcore.dll  C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\shcore.dll  6.3.9600.17666
ffmpeg.dll  C:\Users\developer\Documents\DavideB\icconnector\frontend\node_modules\nw\nwjs\ffmpeg.dll   0.0.0.0
USP10.dll   C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\USP10.dll   6.3.9600.17415
PSAPI.DLL   C:\Windows\system32\PSAPI.DLL   6.3.9600.17415
profapi.dll C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\profapi.dll 6.3.9600.17415
USERENV.dll C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\USERENV.dll 6.3.9600.17415
HID.DLL C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\HID.DLL 6.3.9600.17415
ole32.dll   C:\Windows\system32\ole32.dll   6.3.9600.18256
OLEAUT32.dll    C:\Windows\system32\OLEAUT32.dll    6.3.9600.17560
credui.dll  C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\credui.dll  6.3.9600.17415
netutils.dll    C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\netutils.dll    6.3.9600.17415
srvcli.dll  C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\srvcli.dll  6.3.9600.17415
wkscli.dll  C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\wkscli.dll  6.3.9600.17415
NETAPI32.dll    C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\NETAPI32.dll    6.3.9600.17415
OLEACC.dll  C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\OLEACC.dll  7.2.9600.17415
Secur32.dll C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\Secur32.dll 6.3.9600.17415
COMCTL32.dll    C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.9600.18006_none_623f33d3ecbe86e8\COMCTL32.dll    6.10.9600.18006
WTSAPI32.dll    C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\WTSAPI32.dll    6.3.9600.17415
NSI.dll C:\Windows\system32\NSI.dll 6.3.9600.17415
WS2_32.dll  C:\Windows\system32\WS2_32.dll  6.3.9600.18340
NTDSAPI.dll C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\NTDSAPI.dll 6.3.9600.17415
pdh.dll C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\pdh.dll 6.3.9600.17415
SAMCLI.DLL  C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\SAMCLI.DLL  6.3.9600.17415
nw.dll  C:\Users\developer\Documents\DavideB\icconnector\frontend\node_modules\nw\nwjs\nw.dll   0.0.0.0
kernel.appcore.dll  C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\kernel.appcore.dll  6.3.9600.17415
uxtheme.dll C:\Windows\system32\uxtheme.dll 6.3.9600.17415
dwrite.dll  C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\dwrite.dll  6.3.9600.18123
dwmapi.dll  C:\Windows\system32\dwmapi.dll  6.3.9600.17415
NLAapi.dll  C:\Windows\system32\NLAapi.dll  6.3.9600.17415
WINNSI.DLL  C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\WINNSI.DLL  6.3.9600.17415
IPHLPAPI.DLL    C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\IPHLPAPI.DLL    6.3.9600.18264
dhcpcsvc6.DLL   C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\dhcpcsvc6.DLL   6.3.9600.17415
dhcpcsvc.DLL    C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\dhcpcsvc.DLL    6.3.9600.17415
gpapi.dll   C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\gpapi.dll   6.3.9600.18339
wlanapi.dll C:\Windows\system32\wlanapi.dll 6.3.9600.17415
SETUPAPI.dll    C:\Windows\system32\SETUPAPI.dll    6.3.9600.17415
MSASN1.dll  C:\Windows\system32\MSASN1.dll  6.3.9600.17415
CRYPT32.dll C:\Windows\system32\CRYPT32.dll 6.3.9600.17475
WINTRUST.dll    C:\Windows\system32\WINTRUST.dll    6.3.9600.17415
powrprof.dll    C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\powrprof.dll    6.3.9600.17415
MMDevAPI.DLL    C:\Windows\system32\MMDevAPI.DLL    6.3.9600.17415
audioses.dll    C:\Windows\system32\audioses.dll    6.3.9600.17415
clbcatq.dll C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\clbcatq.dll 2001.12.10530.17415
Normaliz.dll    C:\Windows\system32\Normaliz.dll    6.3.9600.17415
wevtapi.dll C:\Windows\System32\wevtapi.dll 6.3.9600.17415
Wpc.dll C:\Windows\System32\Wpc.dll 6.3.9600.17415
ntmarta.dll C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntmarta.dll 6.3.9600.17415
mswsock.dll C:\Windows\system32\mswsock.dll 6.3.9600.18340
DNSAPI.dll  C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\DNSAPI.dll  6.3.9600.17415
fwpuclnt.dll    C:\Windows\System32\fwpuclnt.dll    6.3.9600.18229
rasadhlp.dll    C:\Windows\System32\rasadhlp.dll    6.3.9600.17415
WINSTA.dll  C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\WINSTA.dll  6.3.9600.17415
BluetoothApis.dll   C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\BluetoothApis.dll   6.3.9600.17415
bthprops.cpl    C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\bthprops.cpl    6.3.9600.17415
wshbth.dll  C:\Windows\system32\wshbth.dll  6.3.9600.17415
CRYPTSP.dll C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\CRYPTSP.dll 6.3.9600.17415
bcrypt.dll  C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\bcrypt.dll  6.3.9600.17415
rsaenh.dll  C:\Windows\system32\rsaenh.dll  6.3.9600.18191
PROPSYS.dll C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\PROPSYS.dll 7.0.9600.17415
atlthunk.dll    C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\atlthunk.dll    6.3.9600.17415
DPAPI.dll   C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\DPAPI.dll   6.3.9600.17415
mscms.dll   C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\mscms.dll   6.3.9600.17415
SAMLIB.dll  C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\SAMLIB.dll  6.3.9600.18264
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, find out the problem...

in my controller i was retriving a function present in a factory:

```
$scope.testConnection =  connectionService.testConnection;
```

in my factory

```
    function(endpoint, payload, callback=false){
        $http.post(endpoint,payload)
        .success(function(data){
            if(data.status=="ERROR")
                $rootScope.$broadcast('errorMex',{value:data.message})
            if(callback)
                return callback(data);
            return data;
        })
        .error(function(error){
            log.err(error,'restService - post');
        })
        .finally(function(){
            spinnerMex(false);
        });
    }
```

the proble was the **return** statement. I was closing the memory where the call back will work after the response of node server.

with that code it work fine:

```
    function(endpoint, payload, callback=false){
        $http.post(endpoint,payload)
        .success(function(data){
            if(data.status=="ERROR")
                $rootScope.$broadcast('errorMex',{value:data.message})
            if(callback)
                callback(data);
        })
        .error(function(error){
            log.err(error,'restService - post');
        })
        .finally(function(){
            spinnerMex(false);
        });
    }
```